# Can the object returned by `useStore()` ever change?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Can I safely assume that the `useStore()` hook of `react-redux` returns the identical object throughout the lifetime of a component, or do I have to account for the fact that it may change over time?

Background: Using RxJS, I would like to get a stream from the store like so

```
function MyComponent() {
   // ...

   const store = useStore();

   const storeStreamRef = useRef(null);
   if (storeStreamRef.current === null) storeStreamRef.current = from(store);

   // no further assignments to storeStreamRef.current in my code

   // ...
}
```

and I wonder whether this is correct?

If the return value of `useStore()` could be different from call to call, my code would be wrong, since `storeStreamRef.current` would not be updated.

Calling `useStore()` every time `MyComponent` is called, but using it only on the first call looks a bit weird to me; the alternative of monitoring whether the store has changed compared to last time, however, seems odd as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can assume that `useStore` will always return the `same reference` to the object.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks),

`useStore` hook `returns a reference` to the same Redux store that was passed in to the  component.

This hook should probably not be used frequently. Prefer `useSelector()` as your primary choice. However, this may be useful for less common scenarios that do require access to the store, such as replacing reducers.